# Regex check for variations of phone number

Tags: regex, numbers

I need to get phone number from set of text input with several different variations of phone number format.

```
99999999
tel: 99999999
Tel; 99999999
Tel: 99999999
Tel:99999999
Tel: 9999 9999
Tel:9999 9999
Tel: +42-99999999
Tel:+42-9999-9999
Tel:+42-99999999
```

Is it possible to make regex which will match it?

Comment: Just to verify - you *have* the phone number and you want to match it against various representations of the same, right? Do you need to do this dynamically - as in, get the phone number, then programmatically construct the regex, or do you want to construct the regex by hand and then use it?

Comment: Hi thanks for asking, I need to construct the regex by hand and then use it.

Comment: 1) Remove the non digit characters. 2) test the length.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match all of your specified variations:

`[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$`

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, but with this regex only match this format Tel:+42-99999999

Comment: We can rewrite that regex like this: `[+]*\(?\d{1,4}\)?[-\s\.\/0-9]*$`

Comment: I tested the regex against your examples and it matched all of them. Try to add the m flag if you are testing multiple numbers at once